# TimeStamp Epoch Conversion in Kafka Connect Issue

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, epoch, sql-timestamp

Using Confluent Community edition of Kafka and I am doing data transfer from SQL server to Kafka topics in JSON format. Date-Timestamp fields from SQL server are getting converted to epoch milliseconds. But I want to restrict that conversion, can I do that?

I tried using TimestampConverter SMT, but still no effect in result. The data still coming in epoch only.

Please guide for the same.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show your connector configs and data in your topics

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.